# invalid literal for int() with base 10 with GRU module

Tags: keras, deep-learning, text-classification, valueerror

My input is simply a csv file with 50K rows and two columns for Arabic sentiment analyses  : but im keep getting error while trying to train my data on a stacked GRU model

keep getting the below error

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'اللهم اني احسن
>   التدبير فادبر امري'

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.text, df.sentiment, test_size=0.1, random_state=37)
assert X_train.shape[0] == y_train.shape[0]
assert X_test.shape[0] == y_test.shape[0]
tk = Tokenizer(num_words=NB_WORDS,
               filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n',
               lower=True,
               split=" ")
tk.fit_on_texts(X_train)
def one_hot_seq(seqs, nb_features = NB_WORDS):
    ohs = np.zeros((len(seqs), nb_features))
    for i, s in enumerate(seqs):
        ohs[i, s] = 1.
    return ohs

X_train_oh = one_hot_seq(X_train_seq)
X_test_oh = one_hot_seq(X_test_seq)


X_train_seq = tk.texts_to_sequences(X_train)
X_test_seq = tk.texts_to_sequences(X_test)
assert X_valid.shape[0] == y_valid.shape[0]
assert X_train_rest.shape[0] == y_train_rest.shape[0]

max_words = 500
top_words = 5000
X_train  = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train , maxlen=max_words)
X_test = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=max_words)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(top_words, 100, input_length=max_words))
model.add(GRU(100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

# Train
model.fit(X_train_oh, y_train_oh, epochs=3, batch_size=64)

# Final evaluation of the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test_oh, y_test_oh, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))

# Predict the label for test data
y_predict = model.predict(X_test)
```